# Storing/loading duplicate objects in xml

Tags: java, xml

I'm learning java and XML interaction and trying to figure out general approach for storing hierarchy that may include references to the same object. For example, I have a dataset with two lists - authors and books. One of the fields in Book is a list of authors which can consist of some authors that are present in general authors list and some that are not. So hierarchy may have references to duplicate objects inside it, like this:

```
Author author1 = new Author("A");
Author author2 = new Author("B");

List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
authors.add(author1);
authors.add(author2);

Author author3 = new Author("C");

List<Author> bookAuthors = new ArrayList<>();
bookAuthors.add(author2);
bookAuthors.add(author3);

Book book = new Book("book", bookAuthors);

List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
books.add(book);

...

Dataset dataset = new Dataset(authors, books);
```

Now I want to be able to read this kind of hierarchy (in this case to Dataset object) from xml file with saving relations. Is it normal to have id as an attribute for author in xml, only specifying author details once, and then make analyzer restore relations by working with some kind of map of already read ids and corresponding objects? Or is there a more appropriate/common approach? Here's an example xml file's structure that I have in mind:

```
<dataset>

  <authors>

    <author id="0">
      <author_data>
        ...
      </author_data>
    </author>

    <author id="1">
      <author_data>
        ...
      </author_data>
    </author>

    ...some other authors...

  </authors>

  <books>

    <book>
      ...
      <authors>

        <author id="1"/> //author that was specified before

        <author id="2"> //author that was not - receives new id and is specified here
          <author_data>
            ...
          </author_data>
        </author>

        ...some other authors...

      </authors>
    </book>

    ...some other books...

  </books>

</dataset>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what are you trying to do, but as advice, I could recommend using a XML framework like dom4j to work easily with XML and Java. In addition, if you are trying to search relationships between objects, it sounds like you are needing some kind of database or persistence in which perform the lookup. Please give more details in order to provide help.

Comment: Hi, for start I'd just like to read hierarchy from a ready xml file with saving relations - meaning if I should have several references to same object in my hierarchy, I don't want to read duplicates from xml instead. Is xml structure like the one I added to the post and using a map of ids and objects during xml analysis a normal way to do it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a "*normal*" way to do that. I suggest that you define all authors at the beginning, and in the `book` structure use references to the IDs without making a distinction between repeated or not. But this answer is strictly related to structures that I have been seen, and the details depends of the use case, and which things you are going to do with the XML that you generate.

As a final comment, this question has nothing to do with Java, because is general and non-related to the language itself.